# Como puedo arreglar el error: Parameter is not valid

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Tengo un error que no me deja mostrar la imagen guardada en la base de datos pero no encuentro como arreglarlo.

Dice que el error empieza desde:

> ```
> PictureBox1.BackgroundImage = (Image.FromStream(mStream))
> ```

Mi código es:

```
Private Sub Mostrar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Mostrar.Click
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim mStream As New IO.MemoryStream()
        Try
            cadena.Close()
            cadena.Open()
            comando = "Select * from ImagenesPlayStation where codigo = '" & TextBox2.Text & "'"
            con = New SqlDataAdapter(comando, cadena)
            con.Fill(dt)
            If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                TextBox1.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("nombre")
                Dim imageBuffer() As Byte = CType(dt.Rows(0).Item("Imagen"), Byte())
                mStream = New IO.MemoryStream(imageBuffer)
                PictureBox1.BackgroundImage = Nothing
                PictureBox1.BackgroundImage = (Image.FromStream(mStream))
                PictureBox1.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch
            End If
            cadena.Close()
            dt.Clear()
            dt.Reset()
            mStream.Dispose()
            mStream.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Si vas a agregar una imagen de background en el PictureBox, no es necesaria la linea :`PictureBox1.BackgroundImage = Nothing`, elimina la linea que comento:

```
  'PictureBox1.BackgroundImage = Nothing //Elimina esta linea!
  PictureBox1.BackgroundImage = (Image.FromStream(mStream))
```

Comment: También valdría la pena que el OP revise que el valor de `mStream` no sea null.

Comment: Muy cierto aunque esto solucionaría el problema que menciona el OP, "Parameter is not valid", lo que comentas provocaría un ArgumentException https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentexception(v=vs.110).aspx